Trying to transfer SPL token but fails Help Please
I used the following Rust code (now updated) to try to transfer spl tokens between wallets using ATAs of the respective wallets for the given token.
The from.key is the authority for the transfer.
    let transfer_instruction = spl_token::instruction::transfer_checked(
        &spl_token_2022::ID,
        from_acct.key,
        mint.key,
        to_acct.key,
        from.key, 
        &[from.key],
        amount,
        5).unwrap();    
    msg!("Transfer Inst Formed{:?}!"); // Doesn't make it to here
                                       // says, "IncorrectProgramId" ???        
    let required_accounts_for_transfer = [
        from_acct.clone(),
        mint.clone(),
        to_acct.clone(),
        from.clone(),
    ];

    invoke_signed(
        &transfer_instruction,
        &required_accounts_for_transfer,
        &[],
    ).unwrap();

The ATAs were created (in ts) with the following :
tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        keypair,
        mintPK,
        keypair.publicKey, // This for "From"
//        escwallet.publicKey, //Then this for "To"
        false,
        null,
        {},
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );

keypair.publicKey was used for the From Account and
escwallet.publicKey was used for the desination Account
Token22 PID is being used because the mint token includes a 2022 metadata extension!
It doesn't make it past the creation of the instruction.
I get the following error at the ende of the Tx creation:
"Program log: Transfer 100000 from: 4Qeo9ttdf4vCZTC4d2pGq4eqFfkQpxj95t4WGYc2buXV to: 86YUbdsc7z2Y5NdLXeFLwVYfbzVdLjUb1en9XxmJbfb2!",

"Program log: for mint: GSLS3jfAf6F8Bimab8dvAgc3Xz5rewa2KBKumjhoNn11",
"Program log: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IncorrectProgramId', 574155a2-81d8-4c76-b5d1-fff88cd66c8d/src/lib.rs:221:12",

TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb is being used!
What I don't understand, I did the same transaction with Phantom (successfully) and get this

The Phantom transaction calculates compute unit budgets, which I don't, but I don't think this causes my error!
All the parameters are the same !!!HELP!!!

I found the problem!
In creating the transfer transaction I had used:
let transfer_instruction = spl_token::instruction::transfer,
and even though I included &spl_token_2022::ID, as the first parameter, I should have used the following:
let transfer_instruction = spl_token_2022::instruction::transfer as well for the creation of the Tx

You shouldn't put your own program as the program, you need to put the token program you are using. If the token is a normal token, use Tokenkeg program, if it's Token22, use that. These are constants in the spl_token library and you can accommodate both in Anchor using the TokenInterface account type.

OK, thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. Through debug on the Rust program it's using what I expect, in this case, my two ATAs and the token22 account. among the other things. But you're right, something in the construction of the instruction is failing

The "from.key" is the originating wallet's authority. That is correct, right?

I tried SYSTEM_TOKEN_ID (instead of the SYSTEM_2022_TOKEN_ID above) and it got further but seems to crash because it can't find the account. The ATAs are made from a TOKEN 2022 token with a metadata account "built in".

Keep using the Token 22 PID, you should be using the ATA addresses for the to and from, not the wallet. so where you generate the ATA for each account, take the pub keys and pass those in. Based on your answers I can't tell if you're already doing that.

Yes I am using the ATA addresses.

I get the following panic: "Program log: Transfer 100000 from: 4Qeo9ttdf4vCZTC4d2pGq4eqFfkQpxj95t4WGYc2buXV to: 86YUbdsc7z2Y5NdLXeFLwVYfbzVdLjUb1en9XxmJbfb2!",
"Program log: on program: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb",
"Program log: panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: IncorrectProgramId', yet checking the successful tx details of a phantom transfer it shows the exact same parameters.

So... if I use TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, spl_token::instruction::transfer runs fine, but there's a data error when it's executed (Because the token is actually a Token 22. If I use TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, spl_token::instruction::transfer fails with an  Err value: IncorrectProgramId' ????
